# Access Data from localStorageService in directive

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-directive

How do I get data from `localStorageService` in `directive`?

Tried this: `var clientItem = localStorageService.get('clientData');`

Error: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: Still doesn't work?

Comment: Are you using a third-party library for the `localStorageService`? If so, please include a link to that library.

Answer (score 0):

In a directive or anywhere it is the same thing:

```
localStorageService.getItem('clientData');
```

look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)

Answer (score 0):

Services are injected into directives in the construction function of the directive:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function (localStorageService) {
    return {
        link: postLink,
    };
    function postLink(scope,elem,attrs) {
        var clientItem = localStorageService.get('clientData');
    }
}
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#using-dependency-injection)